# How to always use tabs when pressing the tab key?

Tags: indentation, doom, tabs

I use an indentation sensitive language (imba) and I need to always use tabs.

I'm using doom emacs and I'm also writing a wip major mode for Imba. But I press tab and it adds indentation using tabs (a tab or more) followed by two spaces !!

The two spaces drive me insane, and I tried many things to get rid of them:

- Disable electric-indenent-mode `(setq electric-indent-mode nil)`
- `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`

And I tried and removed a couple of other options

```
;; (setq-default tab-width 2)
;; (setq-default evil-shift-width 2)
;; (setq-default evil-shift-round nil)
;; (setq-default tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

Also, I tried enabling editorconfig which is supposed to use the following config

```
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
```

But still, tabs are not working as I wish.

Comment: The key is to set a non-nil `indent-tabs-mode`, and *also* ensure that your mode only ever indents in multiples of `tab-width`.  E.g. if you have a tab width of 4 and indent by 6 columns, it's necessary that there are 2 spaces.  Make sure your mode doesn't do that.

Comment: I suggest you look at Emacs’ built-in mode for Makefiles, where tabs are likewise significant.